# What to do to avoid stack overflow using DTOs?

Tags: java, dto

I'm going to face a Stack Overflow problem (it's so obvious I didn't even need to run the code to find out) and I want to rely on the group's knowledge and experience to find a suitable solution.

I have the following entity classes (Jakarta Persistence or JPA, if you prefer) (for the sake of questioning, they are simplified):

```
public class A_Entity {
   private Set<M_Entity> ms;
}

public class C_Entity {
   private Set<M_Entity> ms;
}

public class M_Entity {
   private A_Entity a_entity;
   private C_Entity c_entity;
}
```

As you can see, **M_Entity** is a relationship class (it contains other attributes, hence its existence). In addition, they contain annotations for the Persistence API and for validation (Jakarta Bean Validation). So for each one, I've declared classes that implement the Data Transfer Object (DTO) pattern:

```
public class A_DTO {
   private Set<M_DTO> ms;
}

public class C_DTO {
   private Set<M_DTO> ms;
}

public class M_DTO {
   private A_DTO a_dto;
   private C_DTO c_dto;
}
```

Next, I declared a mapping interface (to train/reinforce knowledge and practice, I preferred not to use mapping libraries such as [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) and [ModelMapper](https://modelmapper.org/)) (there's a good [article](https://dzone.com/articles/comparing-modelmapper-and-mapstruct-in-java-the-po) comparing both):

```
public interface EntityDTO<T1, T2> {
   T1 toEntity(T2 dto);
   T2 toDTO(T1 entity);
}
```

Finally, I declared three implementations:

```
public class A_Mapper implements EntityDTO<A_Entity, A_DTO> {
   public A_Entity toEntity(A_DTO dto) {
      Set<M_Entity> ms = new HashSet<>();
      A_Entity      a  = new A_Entity();

      for (M_DTO m_dto : dto.getMs())
         ms.add((new M_Mapper()).toEntity(m_dto));

      a.setMs(ms);
   }

   public A_DTO toDTO(A_Entity entity) {
      Set<M_DTO> ms = new HashSet<>();
      A_DTO      a  = new A_DTO();

      for (M_Entity m_entity: entity.getMs())
         ms.add((new M_Mapper()).toDTO(m_entity));

      a.setMs(ms);
   }
}

public class C_Mapper implements EntityDTO<C_Entity, C_DTO> {
   public C_Entity toEntity(C_DTO dto) {
      Set<M_Entity> ms = new HashSet<>();
      C_Entity      c  = new C_Entity();

      for (M_DTO m_dto : dto.getMs())
         c.add((M_Mapper()).toEntity(m_dto));

      c.setMs(ms);
   }

   public C_DTO toDTO(C_Entity entity) {
      Set<M_DTO> ms = new HashSet<>();
      C_DTO      c  = new C_DTO();

      for (M_Entity m_entity : entity.getMs())
         c.add((M_Mapper()).toDTO(m_entity));

      c.setMs(ms);
   }
}

public class M_Mapper implements EntityDTO<M_Entity, M_DTO> {
   public M_Entity toEntity(M_DTO dto) {
      M_Entity m = new M_Entity();

      m.setA_Entity((new A_Mapper()).toEntity(dto.getA_DTO()));
      m.setC_Entity((new C_Mapper()).toEntity(dto.getC_DTO()));
   }

   public M_DTO toDTO(M_Entity entity) {
      M_DTO m = new M_DTO();

      m.setA_DTO((new A_Mapper()).toDTO(entity.getA_Entity()));
      m.setC_DTO((new C_Mapper()).toDTO(dto.getC_Entity()));
   }
}
```

When mapping for class **M** occurs, its methods invoke mapping for **A** and **C**, which in turn invoke mapping for **M**, which invokes for **A** and **C**.........and Boom!!!! Stack Overflow.

Can someone who has already gone through this problem or has an idea, even if esoteric - as long as it works properly - "to give me a light"???

Comment: So, is the idea here that an M contains both an A and a C, but for some reason you want each A and C to know which M's it is part of?  Someone has to be the master.  Either the M controls the creation of As and Cs, or vice versa, but not both.

Comment: As @TimRoberts already pointed out, in the context of a DTO, it seems pointless to have both relation-directions in a DTO; one should be sufficient. I also recommend looking at the concept of DDD, in particular roots and aggregates.

Comment: DTOs are supposed to be specialized to handle only what a particular view needs. Trying to make all-purpose DTOs may not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to create a wrapper object for using your A_Entity and B_entity as lighter references:

- The wrapper would be a subclass of A_Entity and B_Entity or you can create a more sophisticated mechanism using generics, annotations, and reflection;
- The wrapper would hold the original object, but then would expose only the properties you need in order to have a parent reference and avoid returning the set that causes the circular reference;
- Once you create the M_Entity, you'd set up the references pointing to the wrapper instead of the original object.

This is a very similar approach that frameworks such as Hibernate use to handle those situations. It also works fine in serialization scenarios.

I might add that if you are reflecting your Entities as DTO (I cannot tell that per your description, since I am aware that you are hiding parts of no interest to the problem) your design should be reviewed. If that is the case, your DTO is only adding complexity to your code. If you, for instance, expose data through REST API, having those DTOs may be pointless since there are other methods to avoid the exposure of unwanted details.

I hope this helps :)